# How do I access arguments to functions if there are more than 9 arguments?

Tags: bash, function, shell, arguments

With first 9 arguments being referred from $1-$9, $10 gets interpreted as $1 followed by a 0. How do I account for this and access arguments to functions greater than 10?

Thanks.

Comment: You could post an example script where this is not working? I believe $10 should just work and contain to the 10th argument...

Comment: @dkson: no. If you do not use `{}` it consider $10 as $1 and the litteral 0

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ${10}
```

To test the difference with $10, code in foo.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $10
echo ${10}
```

Then :

```
$ ./foo.sh first 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
first0
10
```

the same thing is true if you have :

```
foobar=42
foo=FOO
echo $foobar # echoes 42
echo ${foo}bar # echoes FOObar
```

Use `{}` when you want to remove ambiguities ...

my2c

Comment: I don't know what `bash` _you're_ using but the `$` is greedy: `$foobar` will give you 42, _not_ foobar. If you want `$foo` followed by the literal `"bar"`, you need `${foo}bar`. I won't downvote you since the "real" part of your answer is correct but you may want to fix (or remove) the offending bit.

Comment: @paxdiablo: yes that was a bad untested (my shame) example ... Thank you.

Comment: That's better, so +1. I took the liberty of setting `foo` to `FOO` since there was the possibility of confusion having the variable name and value the same. Hope you don't mind. Cheers.

Comment: @paxdiablo: not at all. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using bash, then you can use `${10}`.

${...} syntax seems to be POSIX-compliant in this particular case, but it might be preferable to use the command `shift` like that :

```
while [ "$*" != "" ]; do
  echo "Arg: $1"
  shift
done
```

EDIT: I noticed I didn't explain what `shift` does. It just shift the arguments of the script (or function). Example:

```
> cat script.sh
echo "$1"
shift
echo "$1"

> ./script.sh "first arg" "second arg"
first arg
second arg
```

In case it can help, here is an example with getopt/shift :

```
while getopts a:bc OPT; do
 case "$OPT" in
  'a')
   ADD=1
   ADD_OPT="$OPTARG"
   ;;
  'b')
   BULK=1
   ;;
  'c')
   CHECK=1
   ;;
 esac
done
shift $( expr $OPTIND - 1 )
FILE="$1"
```

Comment: You probably want `$# -ne 0` instead of `"$*" != ""`

Comment: No need to use `while` and `shift` in some cases. You can use `for arg` or `for arg in "$@"`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to be safe that the whole of a given string is used for the variable name when Bash is interpreting the code, you need to enclose it in braces: `${10}`